# SQL - Calculating overall average without a group?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I have 2 temp tables 1 which stores 2 columns, Locationid, average and the other which stores the overallaverage.

I have successfully populated the Location and average columns but can't figure out how to do the overallaverage then JOIN them together in a SELECT. I can work out the overall average I just cannot figure out how to join it to the 1st temp table.

Example of statement

```
SELECT AVG(Hours) AS OverallAverage
FROM Hours
```

This works out the overallaverage but I need something to JOIN it on i.e. Locationid but if I add Locationid to the select then it will require a grouping and thus give me an average per location not an overall average.

Example of how the table should look

```
LocationID       Average       OverallAverage
1                0.7              0.65
2                0.55             0.65
3                0.45             0.65
4                0.9              0.65
```

Any tips?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `CROSS APPLY`:

```
select l.locationid, h.OverallAverage
from Location l
cross apply
(
  select avg(hours) as OverallAverage
  from hours
) h
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3e7b2/2)

Or even a `CROSS JOIN`

```
select l.locationid, h.OverallAverage
from Location l
cross join
(
  select avg(hours) as OverallAverage
  from hours
) h
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3e7b2/3)

Comment: Is there a difference between `cross apply` and a (standard) `cross join`?

Comment: The `APPLY` is typically used with a correlated subquery or a udf.  In this case, you could use a `CROSS JOIN` -- http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2007/10/18/sql-server-cross-apply.aspx

Comment: thanks. So `CROSS APPLY` is what the SQL standard calls a `LATERAL` query.

Comment: Used the CROSS JOIN and it worked well, not used to using CROSS JOINS, mainly INNERS and OUTERS but thats a good bit of knowledge there, many thanks

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I have actually never heard of a `LATERAL` query before.  I will have to look that one up.

Comment: @bluefeet: I think it was introduced with SQL 99 if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name based on what I am reading, it does look like the `APPLY` is similar to `LATERAL`. Thanks for the tip on that term.

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear to me what you mean with "*but I need something to JOIN on*" (especially that "something"), but you can do something like this:

```
select t2.col1, 
       t2.col2,
       hr.col1,
       avg(hr.hours) over (partition by locationid) as average
       avg(hr.hours) over () as overall_average
from hours hr
  join table_2 t2 on t2.locationid = hr.locationid
```